# Capturing Text inside span using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver and new to it. I  need help please.
My Xpath looks like this:

```
html/body/div[1]/section/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/span
```

Code:

```html
 <div class="mod-content">
   <ul id="issuedetails" class="property-list two-cols">
      <li class="item">
         <div class="wrap">
            <strong class="name">Type:</strong>
               <span id="type-val" class="value">
                  <img width="16" height="16" title="Provision access - HUE"         src="/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10318&avatarType=issuetype" alt=""/>
                   Provision access - HUE           
               </span>
          </div>
```

I want to capture the text "Provision access - HUE". But when I use Selenium webdriver 2

```java
WebElement Type = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*/span[@id='type-val]"));   
System.out.println("Type is "+Type.getText());//Printing Type
```

I am getting output as "Type is Access Request".

Comment: Hi Priscilla, and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's possible that your xpath `//*/span[@class='value']` is finding a different html element, with the text "Access Request". I recommend using a tool such as firefox's FirePath to debug your xpath, to see if that is the problem.

Comment: It looks like the xpath used for "Type" "//*/span[@class='value']" probably finds multiple matches. Webdriver will only return the text for the first match.

Comment: Thank you Lensman. I used firebug and also tried the whole xpath:
html/body/div[1]/section/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/span

Comment: Changed the span[@id='type-val] instead of span[@class='value'] still cannot over come it

Comment: Try using this xpath then `.//strong[contains(text(), 'Type:')]/following-sibling::span[@id = 'type-val']` see provided answer

Comment: Can you share the html of the whole page if possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are more than one `span` elements which has class name `value` and you are locating other `span` because `findElement` always returns first matching locator element, You need to create unique locator which could locate your desire element, May be `id` is the unique here so you should try using `By.id()` as below :-

```
WebElement Type = driver.findElement(By.id("type-val"));   
System.out.println("Type is "+Type.getText());
```

If `id` also isn't unique here, try using below xpath :-

```
WebElement Type = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//strong[contains(text(), 'Type:')]/following-sibling::span[@id = 'type-val']"));   
System.out.println("Type is "+Type.getText());
```